# NASM debug symbols for Windows?

Tags: windows, debugging, gdb, nasm

I am trying to learn x86 assembly on Windows. I can assemble and link a program successfully using:

```
    nasm -f win32 -g sandbox.asm -l sandbox.lst
    ld -mi386pe -o sandbox.exe sandbox.obj
```

But when I try running my program with gdb, it says that it can't find the debug symbols. Nasm says that only the "null" debug symbol format is available for win32. Does this mean that it can't generate debug symbols for windows? If so, then how can I debug my program on windows?

Here is the example program that I am using:

```
section .data

section .bss

section .text

global start
start:
    mov    ebp, esp
    mov    eax, 0
    ret
```

Comment: Can you post the simplest `.asm` program with which you can reproduce this problem?

Comment: There, I posted the code.

Comment: You could always compile it to `elf` format with `nasm -f elf -g sandbox.asm -l sandbox.lst` and link it as Windows PE file with `ld -mi386pe -o sandbox.exe sandbox.o` (note that `sandbox.obj` is now `sandbox.o`)

Comment: @SeanRamey No debug info can be generated for `-g -f win32`. See [Manual 2.1.12](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.12). But @MichaelPetch has your solution.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you so much! But, now I would like to know why this works? I thought that elf object files couldn't be assembled and linked on Windows and still work? Does the linker convert it back to Win32 or something? Also, why don't you go ahead and add your answer to my question officially so you get credit?

Comment: The object files (elf uses `.o`) extensions generated by ELF(ELF aka ELF32) are just another linking format. _LD_ supports a variety of object file types, and it can pull together a variety of types and emit an executable from them. ELF files have a variety of debugging formats associated with it - `stabs` and `dwarf` are common. The unfortunate side effect is that if you intend to link against ELF objects they won't be understood by a Microsoft linker. If you don't intend to use a Microsoft linker then it shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: If you use `-f win32` with NASM, the object files (`.obj`) generated should be compatible with the Microsoft linker.

Comment: If using a linker (like _LD_), it decides the final layout of the executable, and associated executable header data. That is what the `-m` option on _LD_ is used for. `-mi386pe` is the 32 Bit portable executable format understood by Win32 OSes

Comment: @Michael Petch Ah ok, I see now! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the debugging format to include in your binary (sometimes there is not one by default)

try `-gcv8` instead of `-g`